# Здравствуйте, подскажите, как исправить ошибку scale.default(Y, scale = scale) : объект 'list' не может быть преобразован в тип 'double'

Tags: r

Пытаюсь посчитать

```
macrophPot2.partial.rda <- rda(macrophPot.hel, env.Control, env.Carp, env.Rudd)
```

Другой вариант

```
macrophPot2.partial.rda <- rda(macrophPot.hel, ~ env.Control, ~ env.Carp, ~ env.Rudd)
```

выдает ошибку

```
Ошибка в scale.default(Y, scale = scale) :
  объект 'list' не может быть преобразован в тип 'double'
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть дело и как исправить?

Comment: macrophPot.hel - таблица зависимых переменных 6 столбцов 4 строки. env.Control и др. 3 таблицы с управляющими факторами, 3 столбца 4 строки в каждой

Comment: Добавляйте уточнения в вопрос (кнопка "править")